# EDI in Informatica

Tags: mapping, edi, informatica, informatica-powercenter

i am trying to map EDI 834 XSD with transaction tables in database.

I want to know some things

1> DO i need to take one expression transformation for one segment from 834 xsd means 1 expression for ISA, one for GS, one for ST and so on

2> whwn ever i am tring to  join two expression through joiner, it is sotrting all the values which is disurbing  every things

EX. there are 2 ST in one 834 input file and there are 2 INS coresponding to them

```
in EXP1
ST
123
547
```

and in EXP2
INS
549
963

they are in 2 expressions, now when i am trying to join these 2 expression through a dummy condition the output that i am getting is

```
 
ST      INS
123     549
123     963
547     549
547     963
```

means there is no relation whether which INS belong to which ST

the output should be

```
ST     INS
547    549
123    963
```

Is there any other solution to it.

Can someone plese tell me how can to do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [EDI mapping in Powercenter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419592/edi-mapping-in-powercenter)

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are trying to extract native EDI message with powerCenter. 
Informatica has a specific offering for EDI processing - a product called B2B DataExchange, which includes built in libraries for EDI messages, that will automatically convert the native EDI message to XML, which you could handle more easely using plain PowerCenter.

For more information, please refer to http://www.ablinkconsulting.com/what-do-we-do/edi-practice-solution/  , to find information on an EDI use case, and some informative blogs.

A.B Link offers a full service portfolio, focusing on architecture, analysis, implementation and consulting of Informatica B2B product suite

Answer (score 0):

The problem would seem to be the dummy join condition is failing.

I suggest that in all of your input `Expression`s you add a port that acts as a row count.

- Add a variable port `V_COUNTER` (Expression: IIF(V_COUNTER=0,1,V_COUNTER+1))
- Add an output port `O_COUNTER` which outputs the value `V_COUNTER`

And you change you `Joiner` to join on these new `O_COUNTER` ports.